# Call Java method from C++ on android ndk

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I create Androidd NDK OpenGL ES application so I want to call Java method from NativeActivity, in main.cpp file I have JNIEnv* which I pass it to another classes where I want to call the Java method:

```
JNIEnv* env= manager.env;//I pass this pointer from main.cpp 
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/game/JavaMethods");//Here I get the exception
jstring jstr1 =env->NewStringUTF(imgURL.c_str());
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "Share", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(clazz, mid, jstr1);
```

I get `SIGABRT` crash if any env method called.
I am not expert in JNI so I am confused where is the wrong.

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni you can't reuse `Jnienv` on a different thread

Comment: @AlanBirtles So I shared the VM then GetEnv but I got NULL, any idea?

Comment: see `AttachCurrentThread`